# Leer datos de una API JSON externa con PHP

Tags: php, json

Estoy leyendo un archivo `json` externo (A través de una `URL`) y puedo obtener los valores del primer contenido sin problema, pero el del segundo contenido no, me imagino que el problema se debe a los corchetes "[ ]" al inicio y final.

Alguna sugerencia para solventarlo? hay alguna otra manera para obtener 2 o más valores sin repetir el código `echo:`,

**Ejemplo**:

```
echo "Data: ". $json_data{"last_name"}
```

y

```
echo "Data: ". $json_data{"age"}
```

Contenido url_01:

```
{
    "name": Karl, 
    "last_name": Smith, 
    "age": 35
}   

$url = "url_01";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
echo "Data: ". $json_data{"name"}
```

Funciona bien!

Contenido url_02:

```
[
 {
    "name": Karl, 
    "last_name": Smith, 
    "age": 35
  }
]

$url = "url_02";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
echo "Data: ". $json_data{"name"}];
```

No funciona bien!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que tienes que diferenciar es que en el primer ejemplo el JSON que te llega es un **objeto** mientras que el segundo es un **array que contiene un objeto**.

Un objeto se define por los corchetes `{}` y un array por los brakets `[]`.

Por lo tanto, en tu segundo ejemplo, tienes un `array` con una sola posición y en la cual tienes contenido un objeto.

Teniendo en consideración todo esto, podrías leer tu variable de la siguiente manera:

```
echo "Data: ". $json_data[0]["name"];
```